# Ajax post to MVC controller sends null

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send this `fullp` array to my controller but it keeps sending a null value.
This is my controller

```
public ActionResult GetGradeznaParcela(string id)
 {
   var result = dataRepo.GetGradeznaParcela(id);
   return Json(result);
 }
```

and this is my JS function where I get a value from a textbox and populate the `fullP` array with it.
When I print out the array with `console.log` it has the correct value
but for some reason I am not sending the data correctly to the controller. I am missing something out.

```
function fillParcel() {
        var parcelURL = window.rootUrl + 'DUP/GetDUPbyID';
        var input = ($("#buildParcelID").val()).trim();
        var regExp = input.match(/^[0-9][0-9]?#[0-9][\.0-9]*?#[0-9][\.0-9A-Za-z]*?$/);

        if (regExp != null) {
            $("#loader").show();
            var inputArray = input.split("#");
            var dup = inputArray[0];
            minParc = inputArray[1] + "." + inputArray[2];
            fullP = inputArray[0] + "#" + inputArray[1] + "#" + inputArray[2];

            var fullLink = parcelURL + "?id=" + dup;
            $.getJSON(fullLink, function (dup) {
                $.each(dup, function (index, value) {
                    $("#DUPid").val(value.imE_MAK);
                    $("#odlukaDup").val(value.odluka);
                    $("#datumDup").val(value.datumdones);
                });
                $("#loader").hide();
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: window.rootUrl + 'DUP/GetGradeznaParcela',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'id': fullP
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success")
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("alert");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `dataType: 'data'` - that's not a valid data *type*

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Try: `data: { 'id': fullP },` - your action is expecting a parameter named "id" but if you stringify then you send a string without a name - so the mvc binding doesn't know they match.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks. That did the trick. Can you post again as an answer so I can mark it? :)